# How do I prevent commas in a number input in IE

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input

A number input on Chrome

```
<input type="number" />
```

Does not allow commas, only numeric,"e", and "."

However, on IE11 the number input does allow commas (2,000)

Is there an HTML way to normalize this behavior across number inputs? Should I not use the number input? How do I account properly for regions?

Looking for either an HTML or JS solution

Thanks!

Comment: use regex in the pattern attribute to suppress commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another IE issue.

As far as I know, the only way to fix this is using JS:

```
input.addEventListener("input", function () {
  input.value = input.value.replace(/,/g, ".");
});
```

Note that in most regions, a comma is used as a decimal separator.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this. Really annoying that asking a (reasonable I believe) question gets me -2 points! But after looking into it more I think it probably makes most sense to just use a text input and then write a script to normalize and go region by region